# Knapsack recursive algorithm: help debug

Tags: ruby, knapsack-problem

What is wrong with the following knapsack recursive definition? I agree that it is written a bit quirkily (a better version would split vals and weights, and carry an index over the recursive calls), but I am still interested in knowing why this version does not work. I started at it for an hour, but no avail.

```
# Knapsack 
def k(items, w)
  if w == 0 || items.size < 1
    return 0
  end

  current_item = items.shift

  if current_item[1] > w
    return k(items, w)
  end

  right = current_item[0] + k(items, w - current_item[1]) 
  left  = k(items, w) 

  return [right, left].max
end
```

Running:

```
puts k([[5,10],[3,11],[7,25],[1,7]], 40)
```

gives me 9, although 12 is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the calls `#shift` are modifying the *same* array, removing an item.

To debug this try printing `items` for each call to `k`

One solution is to replace:

```
current_item = items.shift
```

with

```
current_item, *remaining_items = items
```

and then update all the recursive calls to use `remaining_items`.

---

As an example that might make it clearer why the mutation leads to the wrong result, consider the very first call:

The item `[5,10]` will fit in the knapsack so we evaluate `right`.  Each recursive call will mutate `items` and remove one entry. By the time you come up the stack to evaluate any `left`, the `items` array is empty.

Comment: I was actually aware of the fact that shift mutates, I just didn't think it would be a problem, considering that all subsequent calls do in fact take the remaining items. My guess as to why your solution worked is that when the stack calls backtrack they find that the items array is mutated. It's hard to wrap my head around it, but I think that's the reason.

Comment: n_x_l, the problem is that when `right = current_item[0] + k(items, w - current_item[1])` is executed `items` is modified, so `left  = k(items, w)` does not do what you want. Try changing the latter to `left = k([current_time, *items], w)`, though I would not suggest that as a fix. Get rid of `shift`.

Comment: @n_x_l I've added a bit more detail to the answer to try to help explain why the mutation leads to the wrong result. _the stack calls backtrack they find that the items array is mutated_ - this is pretty much right. If you were only going down recursively it may not be a problem, but the recursion involves coming back up the stack and then down again (to evaluate `left`) and so it's not a simple case of subsequent calls needing increasingly shifted remaining items.